# Got an unexpected eeror Blog' object has no attribute 'slug'

Tags: html, django, django-models, django-views

Blog' object has no attribute 'slug'

here im trying to to if i click the blog link it will redirected the blog page so i created an tml page called blog.html and i click the readmore link it will redirected to the blogdetail page but i got an unexpected eror

'Blog' object has no attribute 'slug'

Read More 
shows in this line

also it shows an error in blog view
return render(request, 'main/blog.html', context)

Model

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    content = RichTextField()
    posted_by = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/blogs')
    posted_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self) :
        return self.title
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        from django.urls import reverse
        return reverse("blog_detail", kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

    class Meta:
        db_table = "core_Blog"

def create_slug(instance, new_slug=None):
    slug = slugify(instance.title)
    if new_slug is not None:
        slug = new_slug
    qs = Blog.objects.filter(slug=slug).order_by('-id')
    exists = qs.exists()
    if exists:
        new_slug = "%s-%s" % (slug, qs.first().id)
        return create_slug(instance, new_slug=new_slug)
    return slug

def pre_save_post_receiver(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    if not instance.slug:
        instance.slug = create_slug(instance)

pre_save.connect(pre_save_post_receiver, Blog)
```

View

```
def BlogView(request):
    blog = Blog.objects.all()
    context ={
        'blog' : blog
    }
    return render(request, 'main/blog.html', context)

def BlogDetail(request,slug):
    blog = Blog.objects.filter(slug = slug)

    if blog.exists():
        blog = Blog.objects.get(slug = slug)
    else:
        return redirect('404')
        
    context = {
        'blog' : blog,
    }
    return render(request, 'main/blog_detail.html', context)
```

HTML

```
                                        <a href="{{i.get_absolute_url}}"> Read More <span class="icon"></span></a>
```

if i click the url it will redirected to the blog details page

URL

```
path('blog/<slug:slug>',BlogDetail, name='blog_detail'),
path('product/<slug:slug>',ProductDetail, name='product_detail'),
```

My problem

here im trying to to if i click the blog link it will redirected the blog page so i created an tml page called blog.html and i click the readmore link it will redirected to the blogdetail page but i got an unexpected eror

'Blog' object has no attribute 'slug'

Read More 
shows in this line

also it shows an error in blog view
return render(request, 'main/blog.html', context)

Can you help me to solve this bug

Comment: Your `Blog` model has no field with name `slug`. So when you want to get object or filter queryset with `slug` field, then django gives error.